# Sextante "temp" folder?

Tags: qgis, sextante

I have a german Windows and the problem is when I'm using sextante tools the log tells me that I have issues with the folder `dokumente und einstellungen`

> (C:\Programme\Quantum GIS Lisboa>saga_cmd grid_tools "Reclassify Grid
>   Values" -INPUT "C:\Dokumente und
>   Einstellungen\user\sextante\tempdata\1353407599.88104.sgrd" -METHOD 0
>   -OLD 129 -NEW 0 -SOPERATOR 0 -MIN 0 -MAX 1 -RNEW 2 -ROPERATOR 0 -RETAB C:\Dokumente und
>   Einstellungen\user\sextante\tempdata\1353407599.88105.txt -TOPERATOR 0
>   -NODATAOPT       -NODATA 0 -OTHEROPT        -OTHERS 0 -RESULT "C:\Dokumente und
>   Einstellungen\user\sextante\tempdata\sagareclassifygridvalues102.tif.sgrd"
>   **Unexpected parameter 'und'**)

Is it possible to change the temp folder location?

Answer (score 2):

Here: `-RETAB C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\user\sextante\tempdata\1353407599.88105.txt`

should be quotes around the complete path, as given for the other files.

Comment: I'm using the saga tool "Reclassify Grid Values". I have no influence to the script.

Comment: I can confirm it here, and will open a ticket for it. In C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\user\sextante folder, there is a file named saga_batch_job_bat. I opened that, and added the missing quotation marks as mentioned above, and got he batch running without error.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. I have found more issues with the sextante saga tools. Where can I create a ticket for that?

Comment: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6737. You must register at osgeo.org first, before you can login at hub.qgis.org: http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Bugreports

Comment: Should be fixed now. Probably only with Qgis Master.

Comment: How do I install the master version (via OSgeo4W expert installation?)? I tried this but i always have the 1.8 Lisboa version on my PC.

Comment: You get another OSGEo4w icon on the screen. Start that, and enter "qgis-dev.bat" manually. If it works, you can set a desktop link to this bat, located at C:\OSGeo4W\bin. Don't start qgis-dev.exe, it will not run alone.

Comment: Didn't you get a OSgeo4W folder in Start menu? There should be an entry Quantum Gis Desktop (1.9.0)

Comment: No there is no 1.9.0 version. I have installe (expert installation) the qgis-dev quantum gis nightly built of the master 1.9.0-117. Do I have to install something more?

Comment: Strange, but qgis-dev.bat should work anyway. You can look into C:\OsGeo4w\var\log\setup.log.full for error messages. by the way, can you update sextante plugin inside Lisboa to version 1.0.8?

Comment: When I try to install the sextante update 1.0.8 an error shows up (cannot import name runalg). I can not find the qgis-dev.bat. I only have the qgis-dev.exe file in my folder.

Comment: Same error here, I filed a bug report: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6761. For the missing bat, I guess you have to go through the logfile. If successfull, you should have a qgis-dev.bat.done in etc\postinstall folder.

Comment: Now it works. The sextante toolbox has been updated. The tool works fine. But I did not find a 1.9.0 Lisboa version. The qgis-dev.bat is not in my folders.

Comment: The qgis-dev.bat.done is in the etc\postinstall folder. But where can I start the qgis-dev.bat?

Comment: Sorry! After reinstalling I got it (1.9.0). But now I tried to use the saga reclassify grid values tool. It doesnt work in the same way like the SAGA GUI works! After using shape to grid tool I got a raster. The non data values have been defined (automatically) as 129. I tried to reclassify these values as -1. After that I got a raster which has been changed all values...not just the 129 values to -1.

Comment: I think you should open a new topic for that.